# JSON Schema: verifying object's values, without keys

Tags: arrays, json, object, jsonschema

Not to confuse anybody, I'll start with validating arrays...

Regarding arrays, JSON Schema can check whether elements of an (((...)sub)sub)array conform to a structure:

```
"type": "array",
"items": {
  ...
}
```

When validating objects, I know I can pass **certain keys** with their corresponding value types, such as:

```
"type": "object",
"properties": {
  // key-value pairs, might also define subschemas
}
```

But what if I've got an **object** which I want to use to validate **values only** (without keys)?

My real-case example is that I'm configuring buttons: there might be *edit*, *delete*, *add* buttons and so on. They all have specific, rigid structure, which I do have JSON schema for. But I don't want to limit myself to `['edit', 'delete', 'add']` only, there might be `publish` or `print` in the future. But I know they all will conform to my subschema.

Each button is:

```
BUTTON = {
  "routing": "...",
  "params": { ... },
  "className": "...",
  "i18nLabel": "..."
}
```

And I've got an **object** (not an array) of buttons:

```
{
  "edit": BUTTON,
  "delete": BUTTON,
  ...
}
```

How can I write such JSON schema? Is there any way of combining `object` with `items` (I know there are object-properties and array-items relations).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `additionalProperties` for this.  If you set `additionalProperties` to a schema instead of a boolean, then any properties that aren't explicitly declared using the `properties` or `patternProperties` keywords must match the given schema.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": {
    ... BUTTON SCHEMA ...
  }
}
```

http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor64

Comment: true JSON Schema expert you are :)

Comment: What about if you want to make an array-like rule that there must be at least 1 key value pair? Is that also doable?

Comment: @majorBummer Yep, just add `"minProperties": 1`

Comment: Now that I'm using additionalProperties to specify the keys in my "sub-object", how do I say that I don't want any additional properties besides those specified keys? Thanks again!

Comment: @majorBummer Not sure what are asking.  Any additional properties have to match the schema.  There can't be any other additional properties.